# Terminal not working properly

Tags: command-line

I am new to Ubuntu and I am using it virtualized on mac (by virtualbox). When I tried a simple command on Terminal (eg. gedit) I get it open but...
Terminal stays stucked. The user@computer:~$ doesn-t appear anymore. The only way is to close gedit application. Is that normal? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the simple command?

Answer (score 2):

If you just type

```
gedit
```

then the `gedit` command stays in the shell's *foreground*. If you want it to return to the prompt so you can enter other commands you need to put the first command in the *background* - you can do that when you invoke it by adding the `&` character

```
gedit &
```

If a command is already running in the shell and you want to background it, you can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to stop current jobs

```
$ gedit
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 gedit
```

and background a job using its job number, which will return you the prompt

```
$ bg 1
[1]+ gedit &
$
```